# Linear Regression between two leadership styles

Tags: regression, correlation, linear

Yesterday, I made a liner regression analysis between a leadership style (a) and another one (b), with the idea that A predicts B strongly (and I found it so), after doing correlation between two of them which yielded high correlation (about r=0,80), but my supervisor told me that you do not do regression for it, I could not understand and make sense what he tried to say, can someone clarify?  it means that doing linear regression for two variables of leadership is illogical, or doing correlation is enough and no need for regression? why?

Comment: It is not clear how leadership is quantified, so it is a bit difficult to second guess what the problem is. Fill in some of the blanks, maybe show us data, then we may be able to help.

Comment: Hi Carl, many thanks, I was trying to see the effect of authentic leadership on ethical leadership (both were 15-10 itemed short scales with 5-likert type "disagree to agree"), I distributed scales to collect information from employees in companies. I found high correlation  (0.80) and then performed simple regression analysis which was also high around .60. He told me "With just two variables, there is no need to use regression analysis" and did not accept my findings, so why do we have simple linear regression in the books! I hope it is clear now

Comment: Nope. Clear as mud. One cannot arbitrate between opposing concepts based on a rant. Fill in the blanks, document your problem enough for people to give advice, please.

Comment: Sorry, I should better state this way: Do authentic leadership(a) predict ethical leadership (b) according to perceptions of the employees in the sample?... it was my research question, I collected data by surveys which included items like "my manager cares high ethics". Upon entering the data into Spss, I checked correlation value between A  and B and then did simple linear regression to see if my question was answered or not.

Comment: [Authentic leadership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentic_leadership) is an approach to leadership that emphasizes building the leader's legitimacy through honest relationships with followers which value their input and are built on an ethical foundation....there have been...high-profile criticisms of the theoretical basis of the construct, which...said to be...on "shaky philosophical and theoretical foundations, tautological reasoning, weak empirical studies, nonsensical measurement tools, unsupported knowledge claims and a generally simplistic and out of date view of corporate life".

Comment: You know, corporate mantras are like viruses that CEO's catch in that social circle. "Continuous quality improvement," etc. the names of disingenuous failed strategies, e.g., [ISO 9001](https://elsmar.com/elsmarqualityforum/threads/iso-9001-and-other-quality-standards-dont-work-comments.555/), that sounded reasonable enough to get a new CEO a job is very long, and illustrates a cupidity of vapid proportions.

Comment: Do you actually want to predict one from the other or do you want to see if they measure the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what your professor is thinking (and he may be wrong) but my best guess is that he is saying that one leadership style cannot depend on the other leadership style.

Let me use another example to try to clarify.

Suppose you are looking at the relationship between height and weight in adult male humans. Then, mathematically you could:

1. Find the correlation of the two.
2. Do regression with height as the IV and weight as the DV
3. Do regression with weight as the IV and height as the DV

The math works for all three, but 3. doesn't make any sense. That's not because of statistics, that's because of how human bodies work. You don't get taller by gaining weight (although that would be nice!)

So, your professor might be saying that your idea of regressing one leadership style on the other is like 3, above. But if he is saying that, he should not have accepted your proposal and he should offer some advice on alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I think he was trying to say what you implied, but he directly wrote "With just two variables, there is no need to use regression analysis" and I thought correlation is ok, no need for regression.